# Add one day to date (string format) when the input string format is not known

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.x

I have the format
`day/month/year`

And I have a task to define a function that takes a `date` and returns the date with 1 day increased
Example:

`next_day("13/1/2018")` returns `14/1/2018`

`next_day("31/3/2018")` returns `1/4/2018`

How can I do that, I don't know how to do this when the function takes `date` not `day`, `month`, `year`.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Can you be more precise in what you don't know how to do?

Comment: Step 1: Google "python parse date string". Step 2: Google "python add 1 day to date". Step 3: Google "python convert date to string". Step 4: Profit.

Comment: @Robᵩ I need to convert the `date` as it will be a string so I can split it into day/month/year without changing it from being a string.

Comment: Why would you want to not change it from being a string? A `datetime`/`date` object would be much easier to deal with.

Comment: @MarwanKhaled - If that is all you want to do, then `date = '13/1/2018'` / `day, month, year = date.split('/')` should work for you.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, please consider accepting (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using the 3rd party `dateutil` library and `datetime` from the standard library.

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser

def add_day(x):
    try:
        new = parser.parse(x) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    except ValueError:
        new = parser.parse(x, dayfirst=True) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return new.strftime('%d/%m/%Y').lstrip('0').replace('/0', '/')

add_day('13/1/2018')  # '14/1/2018'
add_day('31/3/2018')  # '1/4/2018'
```

Trying to perform the same logic with `datetime` will be more restrictive, which is probably not what you want since it's not obvious you can guarantee the format of your input dates.

**Explanation**

- Try parsing sequentially with month first (default), then day first.
- Add a day using `datetime.timedelta`.
- Use string formatting to remove leading zeros.

**Pure `datetime` solution**

```
import datetime

def add_day(x):
    try:
        new = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y') + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    except ValueError:
        new = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y') + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return new.strftime('%d/%m/%Y').lstrip('0').replace('/0', '/')

add_day('13/1/2018')  # '14/1/2018'
add_day('31/3/2018')  # '1/4/2018'
```

Comment: I like it but the second ValueError should raise an error I'd say.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped, but can't I do this with python 2? dateutil is a python 3 function.

Comment: @MarwanKhaled, sure I've added that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function to return the current date at least.

extension Date {

```
var withWeekDayMonthDayAndYear: String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: self)
}
```

Then use the extension..
((Date().withWeekDayMonthDayAndYear))

It's a start..

Comment: This question is for [tag:python], which your answer does not appear to be written in...